# Filling DataGridView with custom query from a DataSet

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a dataset which contains a table called Sessions. I'm trying to load the results of the query into the DataGrid but I'm not able to do so. The query is stored under TableAdapters within the table in the Dataset. 
Here is my query:

```
SELECT t.*, c.*, s.*
FROM [Transaction] AS t INNER JOIN
Session AS s ON t.SessionID = s.SessionID INNER JOIN
Customer AS c ON t.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
WHERE (s.SessionID = @SessionID)
```

Here is how I call it to fill the datagrid but obviously it doesn't work:

```
grdDetails.DataSource = frmBusiness.SessionTableAdapter.getSessionBuyIns(159)
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? Does your custom query return data?

Comment: @Chris that's exactly what is not working. The datagrid loads with no data.

Comment: Maybe the problem is @SessionId. What happened if you execute the SELECT without WHERE?

Comment: Have you solved this issue? If not, and if the getSessionBuyIns method returns an array of DataRows (not a Datatable) you could be interested by this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468390/binding-a-set-of-datarows-to-datagridview/17476653#17476653