# binding a set of datarows to datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datarow

I have tried the following code, but nothing is displayed in datagridview.

Any Suggestions?

```
string strFilterOption = "dtcolnPurchaseProductExpProductNo=270";
dgvProductExp.DataSource = dtPurchaseProductExp.Select(strFilterOption);
```

Comment: Not a very complete description. But have you tried to do `dgvProductExp.Databind()` ? If so, please post a complete description of the code and the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.80).aspx)

> The DataGridView class supports the standard Windows Forms
> data-binding model. This means the data source can be of any type that
> implements one of the following interfaces:
>
> The IList interface, including one-dimensional arrays.
>
> The IListSource interface, such as
> the DataTable and DataSet classes.
>
> The IBindingList interface, such as
> the BindingList class.
>
> The IBindingListView interface, such as the
> BindingSource class.

Due to the default behavior for databinding with array, you can't set, for the DataSource property, the array of Datarows that the Datatable.Select method will return. From [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/49f95c6d-1e4d-414f-9f02-ba1a839d09be/datasource-datarow):

> The primary one is that the object implements IList or is a
> 1-Dimensional Array.  The thing is, an array has a default behavior
> for databinding - Reflection.  The object type within the array is
> reflected to discover its public properties which are not indexed and
> with value types that can be represented in the grid.  These
> properties are then used as the Fields when the databinding occurs.
> Since the data type in your array is DataRow, there are six public
> properties:  HasErrors, Item, ItemArray, RowError, RowState, and
> Table.  But Item is an indexed property and ItemArray is of type
> Object(), which can't be displayed in a gridview, so these two
> properties are ignored and the other four are shown in the grid.

So another way would consist to create a new DataTable, using Clone method in order to get the schema from the DataTable source, and populate the new DataTable with the array of DataRows.

```
string strFilterOption = "dtcolnPurchaseProductExpProductNo=270";
DataTable cloneTable;
cloneTable = dtPurchaseProductExp.Clone();
foreach (DataRow row in dtPurchaseProductExp.Select(strFilterOption))
{
   cloneTable.ImportRow(row);
}
dgvProductExp.DataSource = cloneTable;
```

Or, you can also do your binding through a BindingSource object and use its Filter property.

Answer (score 1):

Have you test `dgvProductExp.DataSource.Tables(0).Rows.Count` ? .. if it show `0` that's why ..

Or are you sure it's not

`string strFilterOption = "dtcolnPurchaseProductExpProductNo='270'";` ?

Answer (score 1):

In case if someone experiencing a similar issue, the easiest way will be to convert the data row array back to datatable and then setting the grid view data source.

```
dgvProductExp.DataSource = dtPurchaseProductExp.Select(strFilterOption).CopyToDataTable();
```