# Is it possible to bind multiple datasource(data table) with One Datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, dataset, multiple-tables

Hello I`m making a windows application to check and use thread.

I want to make like this.

1. Winfrom design is like this
   [image]
2. In Datagridview I want to bind each rows with each datasource(or table)

for example, as you can see, Process 1 is bind with table1 and Process2 is bind with table2

and when data is loading I want to see that using thread and progress bar in Datagridview column.

So my questions is, Is it possible to bind multiple datasource in one Datagridview.

Please tell me about that or another way to make that.
Thank you.

Comment: Your approach is wrong, you must create only one datasource and then update it's element's properties.

Comment: Oh I see.Do you know another way to make like that??

Comment: Another way? no, there's no way to bind multiple datasources.

Comment: See posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468390/binding-a-set-of-datarows-to-datagridview

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot bind each row with different datasource.
One possible solution could be like this

For each process name / row header, create a variable which will contain the progress status (ex. percentage).

After this, for each row/process name, create a progress bar and bind the progress bar value with designated variable for the process.